# Ruby on Rails: debugging rake tasks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging, rake, ruby-debug

When I write `debugger` it does not start:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `run_init_script' for Debugger:Module
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ruby-debug-base-0.10.3/lib/ruby-debug-base.rb:239:in `debugger'
from (irb):4
```

If I run `rake my:task --debugger`,it returns me to console immediately. How is it possible to debug rake tasks?

Comment: Check this if you want to debug from Rubymine.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4401602/rubymine-debugger-with-rake

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I found the solution.

```
$ gem install ruby-debug
$ ruby-debug rake my:task
```

or on some systems

```
$ rdebug rake my:task
```

Comment: Really though you shouldn't be doing large amounts of logic in a rake task. Most of my rake tasks are one-liners that call a method on a model which is then fully covered with tests.

Comment: I am doing spider based on mechanize and I need debug some lines. All them in methods and not covered by tests yet.

Thank you for the reply.

Comment: @rspeicher, it's useful if you have a seed task

Comment: on my system is `rdebug` instead of `ruby-debug`

Comment: TIP: Add in the beginning `Debugger.settings[:autoeval] = true` that will cause the typical rails behavior where everything you type runs scoped to the `self` where you put the `debugger` call.

Comment: This didn't work for me in Ruby 1.9. See my answer for what did work for me in Ruby 1.9.

Answer (score 27):

Andrey Kouznetsov's answer didn't work for me using Ruby 1.9.3. The ruby-debug gem doesn't seem to support Ruby 1.9. I had to use the debugger gem: https://github.com/cldwalker/debugger.

1. Add `gem 'debugger'` to my Gemfile's development group.
2. Run `bundle`.
3. Add `require 'debugger'` to the top of my rake task.
4. Add a call to `debugger` where I wanted a breakpoint in my rake task.
5. Run the rake task normally from the command line, e.g.: `rake my:task`.

Comment: Another option instead of putting `require 'debugger'` at the top is to put inline `require 'debugger'; debugger`. That way, when you delete the `debugger` statements, you won't forget to delete the `require`.

Answer (score 12):

I highly recommend [**pry**](https://github.com/nixme/pry-debugger) for this

```
bundle install pry
require 'pry'
rake ...
```

In your **rake task** file:

```
binding.pry
```

Answer (score 7):

This approach did not work for me. I just added this in my code:

```
require 'ruby-debug'
# ... code ...
debugger
```

Answer (score 5):

[Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com) has pretty good debugger, built-in. If anybody finds this searching for a way to get it to work with rake, here's a working configuration:

```
{
    "name": "Debug a rake task",
    "type": "Ruby",
    "request": "launch",
    "useBundler": true,
    "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
    "program": "/usr/local/bin/rake",
    "args": ["all"]
}
```

This would run the rake task `all`. You may have to change the path to rake, I didn't find way to run the one in PATH.

Comment: `all` didn't work for me. I used `rvm`s `rake` and I set `args` to the name of my task with a breakpoint on the first line of it and it worked for me.

Comment: @SomeGuyOnAComputer: Hence the sentence "This would run the rake task all". It's just the name of a task I have (/had two years ago).

Comment: my bad I missed that

Answer (score 1):

ByeBug is another one for 2.0+

https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug