# nothing happens when I run rake db:migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails

started a new rails 3 app. I have aded a couple of migrations which were generated through Scaffold. Nothing is output to the console when I run "rake db:migrate", even when I run "rake --verbose db:migrate"

here is a sample migration

```
class CreateBicycles < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :bicycles do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.text :Note
      t.string :Manufacturer
      t.string :Model
      t.date :year_manufactured
      t.integer :view_count
      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :bicycles
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you post your migrations?

Comment: I mean in the body of your question. :)

Comment: Where are you running your rake tasks from? Make sure you are running in the root of your rails directory and that you even have a RakeFile.

Comment: I'm running the command from the rood dir of the project and I have a Rakefile!

Comment: Have you configured your database.yml correctly?

Comment: Yep, I ran the rake cmd with trace, and rpeatedly I get the same output:** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute db:migrate
** Invoke db:schema:dump (first_time)
** Invoke environment 
** Execute db:schema:dump

Comment: What are the contents of the rakefile?

Answer (score 1):

I've met the problem like you.Here is my problem description.

try rake db:version,it returns 0.

try rake db:migrate,nothing happened and no table created,even there are migration files in db/migrate.
try rake db:migrate VERSION=*YourAnyMigrationFileTimestamp*, an exception raised,blames no such migration.

if your problem like me,may be you got or install a wrong rake task which change the default root when running migration task.

to check it,you need debug the third task,(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2663912/rails-debugging-rails-tasks can tell you how to debug rake task).

debug line 548 in activerecord-3.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb,run Dir.pwd,if the 
result is not your app root,there must be some other task change your default task dir.

The following is what i've debugged

(rdb:1) p self.class

ActiveRecord::Migrator

(rdb:1) n

/home/raykin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@r3local/gems/activerecord-
3.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:550

files = Dir["#{@migrations_path}/[0-9]*_*.rb"]

(rdb:1) n

/home/raykin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@r3local/gems/activerecord-
3.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:552

migrations = files.inject([]) do |klasses, file|

(rdb:1) p files

[]

(rdb:1) p @migrations_path

"db/migrate/"

(rdb:1) p Dir['db/migrate/[0-9]*_*.rb']

[]

(rdb:1) l

*** output flushed ***

(rdb:1) Dir.pwd

*** Unknown command: "Dir.pwd".  Try "help".

(rdb:1) p Dir.pwd

"/home/raykin/campus/:/code/campus/db/data_export"

see,the current dir has been changed,cause rails would load all task before running 
migration(there seems a method to skip the all load),and some bad task(just i wrote it yesterday...) change the current dir.

This is exactly not a problem of Rails,but it is really a confused result for user.
hopefully can help you.

Answer (score 1):

I have an absolutely bizarre answer that I have confirmed to be true.  We were building docker containers with `VERSION=<our application version>` and found that none of our migrations would run inside the container, but ran fine outside the container.

Long story short: verify that you have not specified any environment variable named `VERSION`, otherwise the migration will use this as the `target_version` and if it is anything but `nil`, it won't run all migrations.

Relevant bit of code from `lib/activerecord/tasks/database_tasks.rb`:

```
  def migrate
    raise "Empty VERSION provided" if ENV["VERSION"] && ENV["VERSION"].empty?

    verbose = ENV["VERBOSE"] ? ENV["VERBOSE"] == "true" : true
    version = ENV["VERSION"] ? ENV["VERSION"].to_i : nil
    scope = ENV["SCOPE"]
    verbose_was, Migration.verbose = Migration.verbose, verbose
    Migrator.migrate(migrations_paths, version) do |migration|
      scope.blank? || scope == migration.scope
    end
    ActiveRecord::Base.clear_cache!
  ensure
    Migration.verbose = verbose_was
  end
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer solve my problem. I was set VERSION environment variable.